# How to debug Django PayPal IPN?

Tags: django, apache, post, debugging

I'm using [this django app](http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal) to implement PayPal IPN. I'm testing it using PayPal's [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_ipn-link-session), but it's telling me

> IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 500: Internal Server Error

So how can I debug this and see what's really going on? I've dug into code:

```
@require_POST
def ipn(request, item_check_callable=None):
    """
    PayPal IPN endpoint (notify_url).
    Used by both PayPal Payments Pro and Payments Standard to confirm transactions.
    http://tinyurl.com/d9vu9d

    PayPal IPN Simulator:
    https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_ipn-link-session
    """
    flag = None
    ipn_obj = None
    form = PayPalIPNForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            ipn_obj = form.save(commit=False)
        except Exception, e:
            flag = "Exception while processing. (%s)" % e
    else:
        flag = "Invalid form. (%s)" % form.errors

    if ipn_obj is None:
        ipn_obj = PayPalIPN()    

    ipn_obj.initialize(request)

    if flag is not None:
        ipn_obj.set_flag(flag)
    else:
        # Secrets should only be used over SSL.
        if request.is_secure() and 'secret' in request.GET:
            ipn_obj.verify_secret(form, request.GET['secret'])
        else:
            ipn_obj.verify(item_check_callable)

    ipn_obj.save()
    return HttpResponse("OKAY")
```

All *looks* fine and dandy there, but since it's not sending a response to *my* browser, it's kinda tricky to debug. What should I do? I'm trying to look at my apache logs, but it really isn't telling me much.

> 216.113.191.33 - - [06/Mar/2010:14:10:30 -0600] "POST /paypal/ipn HTTP/1.0" 500 16282 "-" "-"

---

I tried to send emails and log messages when this view was called, but neither wanted to work. It's possible that I entered the wrong URL into the IPN simulator :) I disabled the "post required" decorator and went to the page directly to see what was going on. My system started to logging "invalid transactions" as expected (since there was no post-data) and then I took a random stab in the dark and figured that Django's CSRF protection was kicking in and preventing PayPal from sending me the data. Adding the `@csrf_exempt` decorator seems to have fixed it. Yay for guessing errors.

Comment: Try switching to the http://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal fork of django-paypal -- the jonboxall version is old and I gather the dcramer one is the most 'official'/current version. I know this won't necessarily make your 500 error go away, but it'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall having hit (something like) this when using django-paypal too. I can't remember for sure what my cause was, but have you created/migrated the appropriate IPN tables in your database after including the ipn app in your setttings.py?

Comment: Yeah.. dunno if you read the update, but I got it working. Oddly, it still says 500 from time to time, even when I *do* receive the post-back.

Comment: Ah, my proj using django-paypal is on 1.1.1 for now. Good to know that  1.2's CSRF stuff will require some special work. Odd how you're still getting some 500s though

Comment: yeah, i found out why i was getting 500s. it was a legitimate error on my part. the IPN stuff posted fine, but my `payment_was_successful` code had an error in it.

Answer (score 4):

In your django settings.py file, set DEBUG = False

Then for any HTTP 500s (incl. for those being returned to PayPal), you'll be sent a debugging email with all the python stack information.

You'll need to have Django email already set up for this to work, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/ for more info on that

Answer (score 2):

You can install a Poster Add-on and make a POST to IPN notify_url from the browser. You will get a Response with all errors. Pretty helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem and this was what I did wrong. Just in case anyone else is as silly as me...

Do **not** change the method signature from the wiki's
`def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):`  
to something like 
`def show_me_the_money(ipn, **kwargs):`

Reason: in paypal.standard.ipn.models.PayPalIPN.send_signals the listeners are being called with a named argument: `payment_was_successful.send(sender=self)`
Therefore the method **has** to have an argument called sender.