# How to debug PayPal IPN in Django?

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

This is my first time creating an IPN. I'm using [Django-PayPal](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal) and I'm trying to figure out why an account isn't being created when someone purchases. I want to view the errors, but not sure where they would be logged. The Django error log file is empty.

How can I debug this to see what the problem is. Not sure what to fix as the code looks good to the eye.

Thanks so much! Really lost here

Answer (score 1):

At least following post will guide you in right direction:

<strike>[PayPal django Integration](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2008/11/using-paypal-with-django/)</strike>

Also comments on ans in case of any difficulties ..

Updates:

As above URL/website is not exists anymore.
Even I don't what was on that URL :)

But for now visit following URL, I hope it will help you:

[How to debug Django PayPal IPN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393995/how-to-debug-django-paypal-ipn)

Meanwhile, I will try to get best ans doing some RnD

Comment: this link is showing nothing related to payment gateway integration, can yopu please refer some other doc